# When might this photograph have been taken and why?

Tags: england, 20th-century, photo-identification, photo-dating

I have in my possession a postcard that shows an colorised black-and-white image supposedly of my father (born 1927) and an unidentified girl.

[image: Colorised photograph]

I'm pretty certain this wasn't his usual garb at the time (sometime in the 30s?) so am looking (1) to estimate of the ages of the individuals shown (or the date of the photograph) (2) to understand where and why the picture might have been taken and made into a postcard (3) to identify the photographer (long shot).  The post card was never sent and there is no identifying material on the back other than a stamp box:

[image: Stamp box image]

which [this website](http://www.playle.com/realphoto/photok.php) suggests was used on postcards made by K Ltd between 1918 and 1936 -- perhaps this is the manufacturer of pre-printed photographic paper (Kodak Ltd?)

The family lived in Acocks Green, Birmingham, England throughout his childhood.

Comment: Your father looks about ten, so somewhere around 1937, give or take a year or so. Where was he living then?

Comment: He lived in Acocks Green, Birmingham, England from shortly after his birth until he married in 1954 (with time out for National Service).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking sometime from 1937-1940.

Probably the organizer of the presentation invited a photographer and had it printed in photo card style. I don't think this is a post card but just a memorabilia.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am no expert (just the son of a dancing teacher), it looks like they were part of a performance that involved dance.

To me the shoes, shiny floor and stance are the pointers to that.

I think the girl's rear shoe suggests a heel that may be suitable for tap dancing and perhaps your father's too.

If you have not already done so, perhaps a search of local newspapers for the period may turn up a dance school, and with any luck their performances and performers' names.